# What is the name of this tool in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The drop down menu in the top right of the IDE that just provides a very high level view of the current open class that shows every member. Is there a name for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is on the `Navigation Bar` in the `Code View` panel/screen which includes three dropdowns and this is the `Member` drop down. It is used to view and navigate to *members* such as methods and properties etc., within the currently selected class.

Note to gain access to the `Navigation Bar` while editing do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, which will move the cursor to the bar at the top of a code view. One can then select <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the selection to the `member` list.